# Vue.js - document.querySelector returns null value but the element exist

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm following Kevin Powell's tutorial on creating a responsive navbar when I encountered this problem. It seems my 'const primary_nav = document.querySelector(".primary-navigation")' returns a value of null even though the class name exists. This problem is pretty weird to me, any idea why my code returns null?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

const router = useRouter();

const navigations = [
    { path: '/about', name: 'About' },
    { path: '/register', name: 'Create account' },
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login' },
];

const primary_nav = document.querySelector(".primary-navigation");
console.log('primary_nav: ', primary_nav);


const nav_toggle = () => {
    const visibility = primary_nav?.getAttribute("data-visible");
    console.log('visibility: ', visibility);
}

</script>

<template>
    <header class="primary-header flex">

        <div>
            <img class="logo" src="src/assets/Missandei-Logo.png" />
        </div>
        <button @click="nav_toggle" class="mobile-nav-toggle display-none" aria-controls="primary-navigation"
            aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">
                Menu
            </span>
        </button>

        <nav>
            <ul id="primary-navigation" data-visible="false" class="primary-navigation flex">
                <li class="active" v-for="(navigation, index) in navigations" :key="index">
                    <a>
                        <span aria-hidden="true">{{ index }}</span>{{ navigation.name }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>
</template>
```

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77f2A.png)

Comment: I'd say `const primary_nav = document.querySelector(".primary-navigation");` is running before the template has been "mounted" - using `document.querySelector` etc in vuejs is a) an anti-pattern and b) usually never needed anyway, specially in such simple code as yours - your code could possibly work if instead of `primary_nav?...etc` you put `document.querySelector(".primary-navigation")?...etc` - but it's still not how vuejs should be used

Comment: Do not mix plain Javascript with Vue! use `ref`. `<ul ref="primaryNavigation" ... `

Comment: @JaromandaX Hi, thank you for your answer. I'm still a noobie to Vue.js and it's ecosystem.  This advice really helps me a lot in terms of using the full capability of the framework rather than relying on the functions of vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I followed **JaromandaX's** advice and this is what I came up with. Instead of using **Javascript data attribute**, I found this **ref()** method from Vue.js [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) and used it to make a reactive variable called **isMobileNavigationVisible** that has a default value of **false**. Then I just bind it into the class and create a conditional statement where if **isMobileNavigationVisible** is **true** the mobile navigation bar will render.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const router = useRouter();

const navigations = [
    { path: '/about', name: 'About' },
    { path: '/register', name: 'Create account' },
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login' },
];

const isMobileNavigationVisible = ref(false);

const nav_toggle = () => {
    if (isMobileNavigationVisible.value === false) {
        isMobileNavigationVisible.value = true;
    } else {
        isMobileNavigationVisible.value = false;
    }
}

</script>

<template>
    <header class="primary-header flex">

        <div>
            <img class="logo" src="src/assets/Missandei-Logo.png" />
        </div>
        <button @click="nav_toggle" class="mobile-nav-toggle display-none" aria-controls="primary-navigation"
            aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">
                Menu
            </span>
        </button>

        <nav>
            <ul id="primary-navigation" :class="isMobileNavigationVisible === false
                ? 'primary-navigation flex transform-translate-100'
                : 'primary-navigation flex transform-translate-0'">
                <li class="active" v-for="(navigation, index) in navigations" :key="index">
                    <a>
                        <span aria-hidden="true">{{ index }}</span>{{ navigation.name }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>
</template>
```